# Adding and removing class rules in jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

how we use addclassrules and removeclassrules in jquery plugin .
with an examples.

```
$('#form').validate({
});

if ($(this).attr("san") != "") {
    jQuery.validator.addClassRules("san" , { required: true });
    $.validator.addMethod("san", function() {
        required: true
    }, "Please enter your name");
}
else if ($(this).attr("san") == "") {
    jQuery.validator.removeClassRules("san"); 
}
```

Comment: can u please format code?

Comment: what is not working then

Comment: in this code aaclarules working while click , but error not resole after using remove class

Comment: Where is the HTML markup?  What _exactly_ are you trying to achieve.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `.removeClassRules()` method, so that would be one issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes very little sense as you've posted it...

```
if ($(this).attr("san") != "") {
    jQuery.validator.addClassRules("san" , { required: true });
    $.validator.addMethod("san", function() {
        required: true
    }, "Please enter your name");
}
else if ($(this).attr("san") == "") {
    jQuery.validator.removeClassRules("san"); 
}
```

- `$(this)` does not represent anything in the context of your code.
- There is **no such thing** as `removeClassRules()` in the jQuery Validate plugin.
- You're using [the `.addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) improperly.  This method is for creating new rules (methods) from scratch.  You must only put valid jQuery/JavaScript inside the `function(){}`.  `required: true;` inside of a `function(){}` is totally meaningless, and a syntax error.
- You're assigning the `required` rule to a `class` called `san` using `addClassRules()`.  This seems unnecessary.  The whole purpose of [the `addClassRules()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/) is to combine *multiple* standard rules into one (called a compound rule) and assign that compound rule to a `class`.  Then the rules can be applied to input elements simply by using the `class`.
- You're trying to add a method called `san`, create a `class` rule called `san`, while you have an `attribute` called `san`.  **Again, none of this makes any sense**.

---

**Quote OP:**

> *"how we use addclassrules and removeclassrules in jquery plugin . with an examples."*

You start by reading [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org) and looking at the posted examples.  As you can see, there is no such thing as a `removeclassrules` method.

Then when asking a question here, you would clearly describe what you want it to do, what's going wrong, and include enough code for a self-contained example, including the relevant HTML markup.

See:  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thnx for ur guidance @sparky , I will try to make more my questions more accurate in future .

Answer (score 1):

> You just add required set to false in elseif condition.

```
if ($(this).attr("san") != "") {
    jQuery.validator.addClassRules("san" , { required: true });
    $.validator.addMethod("san", function() {
        required: true
    }, "Please enter your name");
} else if ($(this).attr("san") == "") {
    jQuery.validator.addClassRules("san" , { required: false }); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do validation like this also
jquery:

> ```
> function test()
> { 
> if ($("#txtText").val().trim() == "") {
>                 $("#txtText").focus();
>                 ValidateMessage("Please enter title.");
>                 return false;
>             }
> }
>   function ValidateMessage(Message) {
>             $("#pErrorMessage").html(Message);
>             $("#dialogValidation").dialog('open');
>         }
> ```

HTML

```
 <div id="dialogValidation" title="Mandatory message" style="display: none;">
        <p>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
        </p>
        <p id="pErrorMessage">
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: i want to validate through a custom msg , not by css

Comment: ya, using this you can pass customize msg to validate function

Comment: cutom msg working but when I enter any name , msg still appear

Comment: <script>

$('#form').validate({
    
});

 
jQuery.validator.addClassRules("class_1" , {required:true});
$.validator.addMethod("class_1", function() {required:true},"Please enter your name");
 
 
 
</script>this is my code

Answer (score -1):

//this code is for setting the rules

$.validator.addClassRules({
location_name:{
location_name:true,
maxlength:30,
alphabates:true
}
});

//this code is for displaying the which validation message you want.

```
 $.validator.addMethod(
    "location_name", //name of a virtual validator
    $.validator.methods.required,
    "Please enter the city"
    );
```

location_name will be your class name for which you want to give validation.